PySide6: installEventFilter segmentation fault when using QWebEngineView
With PySide6 6.8.0 in linux this code gives segmentation fault:
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QUrl
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Obj(QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, e):
        print(e)
        return False

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#w = QWidget()
w = QWebEngineView()
w.setUrl(QUrl('about:blank'))
obj = Obj()
app.installEventFilter(obj)
w.show()
app.exec()

This happens with QWebEngineView, but not with QWidget.
If I install the event filter in a QWidget there is no error.
This example works well:
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QUrl
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Obj(QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, e):
        print(e)
        return False

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wid = QWidget()
wid.show()

w = QWebEngineView()
w.setUrl(QUrl('about:blank'))
obj = Obj()
wid.installEventFilter(obj)
w.show()
app.exec()


You could run it in the console and tell us what you get.
On Windows with vscode it does not cause problems

It just says: Segmentation fault (core dumped).
With gdb it says it's a SIGSEGV signal in /usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/PySide6/libpyside6.abi3.so.6.8.
I tried with a pyside6 build by myself in ubuntu 24.04 and with pyside6 installed in arch linux in virtualbox.

Could you make the program in c++? To check if the cause is PySide6 or Qt6. Is the same thing happening with PyQt6?

no error with PyQt6

So it's a PySide6 bug, report it.

ok thank you  _______
